# Designing For Configurable Return Values in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I was given a spreadsheet with possible return codes and their description from a third party web service. They look like this (simplified):

```
 Code       Description
 M1         Some description of M1
 M2         Some description of M2
 M3         Some description of M3
 M4         Some description of M4
 P1         Some description of P1
 P2         Some description of P2
 N1         Some description of N1
 N2         Some description of N2
```

In the list above, M codes are classified as **Match**, P codes are **Partial Match** and I codes are **No Match**.

In the C# function, these return values are handled by a `switch` `case` like this:

```
...
switch(returncode)
{
case "M1":
case "M2":
case "M3":
case "M4":
     DoSomethingForMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
     break;
case "P1":
case "P2":
case "P3":
case "P4": 
     DoSomethingForPartialMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);
     break;
case "N1":
case "N2": 
default:
     DoSomethingForNoMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
     break;
}
```

Though the returncodes look similar, there is no naming convention. There may be other return codes in future that may have a different format. But they will still fall under one of the three categories: match, partial match and no match.

In case there are new return codes in the future, with this design, I have to update the code and rebuild, redeploy etc.

There's got to be a better way to do this than to hard code the return values in the code like this. I would like to ask your advice on how to do this in a configurable, scalable manner. Is saving all the possible codes and description in a DB table the best way to accomplish this? 
Thank you.

Comment: What about `switch(returncode[0])`?  Just check the first character.

Comment: when the interface definition changes, and you have to change the code anyway, then it really does not matter. if you want to be able to reconfigure without code changes and deployment, then go for the config file or database approach, which you could then change at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question so it might be opened for answers again. Since the question is currently closed I'll add my suggestion as a comment: You can use lists to verify the code. Some pseudo code: *var _match = new List<string> { "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "future_option" }; if(_match.Contains(returncode)) DoSomethingForMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);* And likewise for the other two categories. Now you can dynamically maintain the lists (e.g. from config), without having to change your code.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just check the first character?

```
switch(returncode[0])
{
    case 'M':
         DoSomethingForMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
         break;
    case 'P':
         DoSomethingForPartialMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);
         break;
    case 'N': 
    default:
         DoSomethingForNoMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
         break;
}
```

Comment: The codes and their classification may not be as consistent in future. That's why I'm afraid to do it like that.

Comment: The questions says new codes will fall in these three categories.  If that's not the case, please edit the question to more accurately reflect future possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If the return codes are somewhat predictable for future use you could use regular expressions.

The pseudo code would look like

```
RegEx fullMatch = new RegEx("some_reg_ex_here");
RegEx partialMatch = new RegEx("some_reg_ex_here");

if (fullMatch.IsMatch(returnCode)
  DoSomethingForMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
else if (partialMatch.IsMatch(returnCode)
  DoSomethingForPartialMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);
else
  DoSomethingForNoMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);
```

Comment: To make it more flexible then you could put each RegEx in either a config file or a database like you suggested.

Comment: I had one problem. Then I used a regular expression. Now I have two problems.

Comment: @MikeHofer So you asked Stack Overflow. Now you have two problems and everybody hates you.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to convert to an enum.

**Code.cs**

```
enum Code
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Match = 'M',
    PartialMatch = 'P',
    NoMatch = 'N'
}

static class CodeExtensions
{
    public static Code ToCode(this string value)
    {
        value = value.Trim();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return Code.Unknown;

        if (value.Length != 2)
            return Code.Unknown;

        return value[0].ToCode();
    }

    public static Code ToCode(this char value)
    {
        int numericValue = value;
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Code), numericValue))
            return Code.Unknown;

        return (Code)numericValue;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var code = returnCode.ToCode();
switch (code)
{
    case Code.Match:
        DoSomethingForMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
        break;
    case Code.PartialMatch:
        DoSomethingForPartialMatch(ReturnCodeDescription);
        break;
    default:
        DoSomethingForNoMatch(ReturnCodeDescription); 
        break;
}
```